# Nginx Content-Type autodetect without file extension

Tags: nginx

There is a way of get/discover a file's MIME-type in NginX and set the proper HTTP header?

The only way I found was using Lua script to execute Linux/Unix command "file -bi "

There is a core NginX config. to do that?

Some example:

```
location /download/ {
  ## Here I have to set default_type "generic" and download it...

  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  add_header    Content-Disposition "attachment";
}

##location ~ ^/discovery/(?<md5>.+)$ {
location /discovery/ {
    alias ./download/;
    default_type    $(how to auto-detect?);

    ##root  ./;
    ##try_files /download/$md5 $uri;
}
```

Comment: I can't put and extension in files, it's names are md5 sums. Until now(), no-one answered this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988615/apache-httpd-vs-nginx-auto-detect-content-type

Comment: Why you can't put extensions? Everyone around uses `<md5>.css` or `<sha1>.jpg` and has no problem. Content type sniffing is error-prone and inefficient, so it wouldn't be in nginx core.

Comment: Maybe you are right and it will cost less time and effort to rewrite some code and use openresty (NginX bundle with lots of Lua extensions) to do so... The files are uploaded by another software with the name without extensions, and don't inform the file type...